# Move files from one directory to another

Tags: xquery, marklogic

Can I physically move files from one directory to another in xquery ?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no MarkLogic function to delete files from the filesystem. The closest you can do is to `xdmp:save` an empty text or binary, overwriting any existing file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean Documents (as opposed to files).

MarkLogic uses [MVCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control).  You must copy and delete - which you can do in a single transaction if the number of documents you want to "move" is not large.

Comment: yes I mean documents. But here I am not talking about deleting from Marklogic database. I am talking about physical deletion of documents from a folder in hard drive. Can I do this with xquery. Please explain in detail.